# How would I go about solving $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2(j+k)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've got this sum that I've contrived. Wolfram has been able to evaluate it to $\frac{\pi^4}{120}$ but I'm not sure how to get there. I've tried switching j and k adding the sum together then averaging but nothing seems to come out it. I have no idea what else to try to do. I definitely feel like it should be in terms of $\zeta(4)$ but I'm not sure how. I have not dealt with double infinite series before.

Comment: Hint: Assume $f(j,k) = f(k,j)$, we have $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty f(j,j+k) = \sum\limits_{1\le j < k} f(j,k) = \frac12 \sum\limits_{1 \le j \ne k} f(j,k) = \frac12 \left[\sum\limits_{1\le j,k}f(j,k) - \sum\limits_{1\le j}f(j,j)\right]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @achillehui's hint, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{j=1}\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{j^2(j+k)^2} =&\ \sum^\infty_{j=1}\sum^\infty_{n=j+1}\frac{1}{j^2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum^\infty_{j=1}\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{j^2n^2}-\sum^\infty_{j=1} \frac{1}{j^4}\right)\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2}\left(\zeta(2)^2-\zeta(4) \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi^4}{36}-\frac{\pi^4}{90}\right)= \frac{\pi^4}{120}.
\end{align}

Comment: Are you able to explain why $\sum^\infty_{j=1}\sum^\infty_{n=j+1}\frac{1}{j^2n^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum^\infty_{j=1}\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1}{j^2n^2}-\sum^\infty_{j=1} \frac{1}{j^4}\right)\\$

Comment: @TomHimler If you make a lattice diagram, you will see that the sum is over half the lattice diagram.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what a lattice diagram is.

Comment: plot the points $(j, n) = (1, 2), (1, 3) (1, 4)...$. This is what I called the lattice diagram.

Comment: Sorry, something is still not clicking. I understand the diagram now, but I'm not sure how the result follows from that.